# module 'caesar' has no attribute 'alphabet'

Tags: python

I am new to Python and don't think I fully understand the 'no attribute' error message that I am getting and wonder if anyone could point me to some hints or explain better what I am missing with the 'alphabet' variable.

```
import caesar

def loadDictionary():
        dictionary = {}
        file = open('dictionary.txt')

        for word in file.read().split('\n'):
        dictionary[word.upper()] = None

        file.close
        return dictionary

DICTIONARY = loadDictionary()

        def isEnglish(plaintext):
        matchingWords=0
        words = plaintext.split(' ')
        for word in words:
            if word.upper() in DICTIONARY:
            matchingWords += 1

        return matchingWords / len(words) >= 0.6

def bruteForce(cihertext):
        for key in range(len(caesar.alphabet)):
        plaintext = caesar.caesar(ciphertext, key, 'd')
        if isEnglish(plaintext):
        print('Key: ' + str(key) + 'Plaintext = ' + plaintext)

        return None

ciphertext = 'Qefp'
bruteForce(ciphertext)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the exact  stack trace that you are getting and for the future please read on [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `caesar` module does not contain anything called "alphabet". Look in the docs or its source code for what the right name is. Take into account that in python, all variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Oh this makes sense! Then I believe I know what I did wrong, as I don't have the caesar module uploaded for it to import from so I will fix this and try again.  Thank you!